# Style <img> to read dimensions from its HTML attributes, not CSS

Tags: html, css, image

Once `width` or `height` properties have been tampered with through CSS, how do you cancel those styles and tell images to read dimensions from their HTML attributes again?

The initial value of `width` and `height` is `auto`, but setting it explicitly doesn't work:

```
img {
  height: 200px;
}

/* ... */

img {
  height: auto;
}
```

It will just make images ignore their HTML attributes completely.

Comment: add !important to the html attribute

Comment: @Cody Guldner: Are you serious?

Comment: lol no. I'm not good with how you use inline html attributes because they are depreciated

Comment: @CodyGuldner don't mix inline CSS styles with HTML attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have access to the initial CSS that sets the `height` on the `img`, then for CSS3 browsers, you can modifiy it to this:

```
img:not([width]):not([height]) {
    height: 200px;
}
```

It uses the `:not` to "not" apply it if the image has either a `width` or a `height` attribute. You can [see results in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GuAgj/3/). This implies that you always want an *attribute* to take precedence over the above CSS. Then, if you actually want to apply a change via CSS, you would need to apply a class or something to the `img`, like so:

```
<img src="blah" class="specialCase" />

img.specialCase {
    height: 200px;
}
```

Which overrules `height` but not `width` settings [as this fiddle shows](http://jsfiddle.net/GuAgj/5/).

Comment: @matija: what do you mean by too specific? It allows for a CSS `height` if no attribute is stated, but at the same time allow the attribute to rule if present. The challenge would be if you have a bunch of `img` tags with attributes that you do NOT normally want to rule, and just a few to apply, in which case they would require classes added to them all using the above method.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, I deleted my comment because it wasn't relevant after your edit. This is a pretty good solution, I'll see if I can make a pull request to the code that sets that `height` attribute.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid it's not possible to cancel a CSS rule this way in order to make an element fall back to its HTML presentational attributes. This is because [presentational attributes are mapped to CSS rules with precedence so low that even a CSS rule with a `*` selector will permanently override them](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#preshint).

Setting a property to its initial value doesn't inherently cancel anything out; it just creates a rule which sets it to the default value that's stated by the spec and participates in the cascade like any other rule. In this particular case, setting `height: auto` doesn't work because all it does is override the values that were originally provided by the HTML attributes and by the previous CSS rule with... well, `auto`.

One possible alternative I can think of is to use JavaScript to delete the offending declarations from the document's stylesheet(s), but I'm not sure if that actually works — I haven't tried it.

Comment: Depending on the OP's particular case, I believe it can be made to work with pure CSS (CSS3) if the OP has access to change the original css for the `img` setting. See my answer. However, that answer assumes that he would want the attribute to _always_ have precedence unless he specifically sets up a class or other selector to specifically apply a CSS driven dimension to the image.

Comment: @ScottS: I've seen your answer - I should clarify that it's not possible to override the original rule as it is, which is how I interpreted the original intent of the question.

Comment: Yes, that part of the question was a bit unclear, and I agree that it is not possible except through javacript (as you state) if access to that is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

setting the width and height to `initial` does result in the original image size, unfortunately this appears to be **limited to Webkit** (Chrome/Safari).

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4cSXR/)

```
img {width: 50px;height: 50px;}
img {width:initial;height:initial;}
```

​

Comment: did some additional testing, looks like when CSS width and height are set to `auto` and the `width` and `height` html attributes are present it does apply those attribute sizes (instead of the CSS sizes) ... http://jsfiddle.net/4cSXR/1/ (worked in IE, FF, Chrome, Safari)

Comment: Your tests are flawed... your width and height attributes are the same as the original image size, so you won't see the difference at all. If you set the attributes to something smaller, like 400x400, then try to set them to `auto` in CSS, it'll restore the image to its original size. Compare http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/4cSXR/2/ (with CSS) and http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/4cSXR/3/ (without CSS)

Comment: The same thing happens if you use `initial` instead of `auto`, because, as mentioned in the question, the initial value for those properties is `auto`. It only works in WebKit because only WebKit understands the keyword; other browsers don't understand it so they ignore it and use `50px` instead.

Comment: Yes, but I want that space to be reserved while the page is loading, to prevent jumps.

Comment: @matija To reserve the space you'd have to have the width/height information server-side to apply styling necessary to the page load.

Comment: @mdmullinax It wouldn't work if the dimensions have been tampered with in CSS. `auto` wouldn't work the way I want, it would act as if no dimension have been set at all.