# CSS - disabling width: auto

Tags: html, css, image

I've got an image which is sized at 32 x 32 (i.e. the width and height attributes). However, the image remains sized at its default of 150 x 150.

Looking at the CSS I can see there's a `width: auto` in the parent CSS file. When I switch this off the image then resizes to 32 x 32.

I'd like to override this without altering the parent CSS file. How do I do this?

Note: I initially tried `width: none` which is not valid CSS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Style <img> to read dimensions from its HTML attributes, not CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14143445/style-img-to-read-dimensions-from-its-html-attributes-not-css)

Comment: Bit of a short cut but you could always use ! Important

Comment: @Toby Cannon: You can't use !important with HTML presentational attributes (see the comments under the linked question), and using it with width: auto won't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the image's max-width to be no bigger than it's parent width. You can set the width/height to initial or inherit, see which one works for you.

**Initial**: Sets this property to its default value.

**Inherit**: Inherits this property from its parent element.

```
.parent img {
   max-width: 100%;
   width: 32px;
   height: initial;
}
```

Comment: Since you have the width: 32px declaration there, you might as well just use that and forget about max-width. Initial is equivalent to auto and has the exact same effect, and inherit only works if the parent element's width is actually 32px, which is unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

you can restrict image height width by adding parent selector to the class for eg. have a look at following example

```
.parent img {
width : 32px;
height:32px;
}
```

Comment: Why would adding a class to the selector allow you to restrict that, or rather, why would not doing so prevent you from doing that?

Comment: Using CSS selector we can easily overwrite inherited css properties, that what I have suggested here. If I am wrong please feel free to correct me.