# How to override the width property?

Tags: html, css, width

How can I override a css `width` so that a competing `width` HTML attribute defines the computed size?

The following example is rendered with a width of 500px, but I want 100px. Assume that the css rule cannot be changed - just masked by a stronger rule.

**Edit for clarification:** I don't want to set an explicit size inline or somewhere else.

```css
img {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placekitten.com/500/500" width="100px">
```

Comment: Try defining it in the `style` attribute of the `img` tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS - disabling width: auto](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29903427/1016716)

Answer (score 4):

You can use inline style to set `width`

```css
img {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" style="width: 100px">
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use !important annotation : 
width: 100px!important;

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `!important` tag:

More info [here](https://www.impressivewebs.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-important-css-declaration/)

Comment: I don't see how this could help here.

Comment: you can use it to give more importance to a certain rule, so it can achieve what you want @h0b0

Comment: Links tend to disappear over time.  Please make your explanation on this page.  Even a couple of sentences could really help people reading this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline css:

```
<img src="http://placekitten.com/500/500" style="width:100px">
```

or you can just remove the px from your current code:

```
<img src="http://placekitten.com/500/500" width="100">
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use like this

```
img {
width: auto;}

<img src="http://placekitten.com/500/500" style="width: 100px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

`img {
  width: auto;
}
<img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" style="width: 100px !important;">`

Answer (score 0):

it easy to work just follow

```css
img{
min-width: auto !important;
width: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" style="width: 100px">
```